# Is it possible to share multiple files with Web Share Target API?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, web-share

Is it possible to share multiple files using [Web Share Target API](https://web.dev/web-share-target/)?
I can select multiple pictures in Google Photos, hit *Share*, then select my PWA. But only one of the selected files is sent to the `share_target` URL given in the *manifest.json*.
This is odd. Did I missed something?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is, yes.

In your Web App Manifest, use something [like this](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/blob/5cdd3a05c6fbc9d1b4c51936bd710266c947632c/web-share/src/manifest.json#L21-L35):

```
"share_target": {
  "action": "/_share-target",
  "enctype": "multipart/form-data",
  "method": "POST",
  "params": {
    "files": [{
      "name": "media",
      "accept": ["image/*"]
    }]
  }
}
```

In your service worker that handles incoming `POST` requests for `/_share-target/`, do something [like this](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/blob/5cdd3a05c6fbc9d1b4c51936bd710266c947632c/web-share/src/js/service-worker.js#L31-L35):

```
const formData = await event.request.formData();
const mediaFiles = formData.getAll('media');

for (const mediaFile of mediaFiles) {
  // Do something with each mediaFile
}
```

There's a deployed example of this code "in action" at https://scrapbook-pwa.web.app/

Comment: Wow thanks again @jeff-posnick !! And kudo for pointing https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/tree/gh-pages/web-share Best resource I ever found about the Share Target API. I was using `formData.get('files');` instead of  `formData.getAll('files');`